# Python how to freeze program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Note: read my comments on the provided answer, it doesn't work**

I have a python program which runs every 5 seconds like this:

```
def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        if not execute_data():
            break
        time.sleep(5.0 - ((time.time() - start_time) % 5.0))
```

The question is how can I make it run from `7:00` to `23:00` only? I don't want to use my computer resources at times where I'm sure my program won't be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def str_to_time(string):
    return datetime.strptime(string, "%H:%M")

def main():
    start = '7:00'
    end = '23:00'
    while True:
        now = str_to_time(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
        if str_to_time(end) > now > str_to_time(start) or str_to_time(end) < now < str_to_time(start):
            print('Working...')
            time.sleep(5)

main()
```

Comment: why you changed my last line : time.sleep(5.0 - ((time.time() - start_time) % 5.0))

Comment: @martin Well, you can change it back in your code, I'm just making it more accessible to future readers.

Comment: Your code doesn't work if start is 7 am and end is 3 am (nearly full day)

Comment: @martin good point

Comment: and... won't you fix your answer?

Comment: @martin Fixed. :)